# Optimization Kronecker product for sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, kronecker-product

I am doing this operation with numpy to get the tensor product of the T matrix (15 times):

```
import numpy as np

T_gate = np.array([[1,0],[0,np.exp(1j*np.pi/4)]])

T = 1
for i in range(15):
    T = np.kron(T,T_gate)
```

Of course this is very slow, also because T is complex, so every value of the final matrix is allocated as a complex variable (even if they have 0j).

I am looking for some way to speed up this process. Note that the final matrix will have a lot of zero elements.

I have tried to save everything in a file, but it seems slower like this, and I have also tried to remove the imaginary part when it is zero, but the nested for loop takes forever.

Comment: Do you mean the arrays have lofs of 0ps, or that you are using the scipy sparse module?I believe there is a `scipy.sparse.kron` function   `sparse` code only helps if the proportiin of 0s is quite high (95%?)

Comment: From 59.5s it's now 38s, which is better, even if it's still slow

Comment: what's the final shape?  Something like 2**15 each way?  sparse `nnz`?

Comment: It's a 2**15 matrix yes. I don't know exactly how many non zero elements, but I suppose max 1 per row